# Invalid Column Name ' ' on Concatenating Columns

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

```
SET @QUERY = 'SELECT ID, CODE, (FIRST_NAME+" "+ISNULL(MIDDLE_NAME,'')+" "+SUR_NAME) AS NAME FROM [Common].[CM_Personnel_MF]
```

Executing above query shows below error:

> Invalid column name ' '.

If I change the query to:

```
SET @QUERY = 'SELECT ID, CODE, (FIRST_NAME+' '+ISNULL(MIDDLE_NAME,' ')+' '+SUR_NAME) AS NAME FROM [Common].[CM_Personnel_MF]';
```

Getting Incorrect syntax as shown below

> Incorrect syntax near '+ISNULL(MIDDLE_NAME,'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape ' with '' (use double single quotes)

```
SET @QUERY = 'SELECT ID, CODE, (FIRST_NAME+'' ''+ISNULL(MIDDLE_NAME,'''')+'' ''+SUR_NAME) AS NAME FROM [Common].[CM_Personnel_MF]
```